# Call plugin on numorous object with different settings

Tags: jquery, dynamic, plugins, settings

Hey Ive been working on a jquery plugin like fancybox for fullscreening images on 
click.

The problem I'm having is that I want to be able call the plugin multiple times with different elements and give them there own defined settings.

Like below where each id has there own fadeIn time

-> ("#id1").fadeIn(200);

-> ("#id2").fadeIn(400);

What is the method to do this as I would love to get this working perfectly :D

Setup element with imagebox example:

```
// Two jQuery Calls with different settings.
$('.smallImage img').imageBox({
    'transition' : 'fadeIn',
    'cursor' : 'pointer',
    'gallery' : 'on'
});

$('.bigImage img').imageBox({
    'transition' : 'fadeIn',
    'cursor' : 'pointer',
    'gallery' : 'off'
});

(function( $ ){
    // Grab plugin settings sent from call - took from jquery developers area.
    $.fn.imageBox = function( method ) {  
        if ( methods[method] ) {
          return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
          return methods.init.apply( this, arguments ); // Sends settings through here.
        } else {
          $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
        }    
    };

    var settings;
    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) { 
            settings = $.extend({
                'transition' : "fadeIn",
                'cursor' : 'pointer',
                'gallery' : 'on'
            }, options);
        }
    }
})( jQuery );
```

Idea's would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: not clear what issue is... you are deinitiely missing an `each` loop to handle multiple elements and need to return `this` to make plugin chainable

Comment: i have `return this.each(function(){ $(this).bind("click", methods.expand); });` Basically I want to be make it possible to create different settings for each element that calls the plugin so one can fade in while other has no fade in.

Comment: Best advice is to read jQuery's [Plugin Tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). All will come clear.